# Meaning of X next to file icon in Project View in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I suddenly saw this marking next to one of the files in my Python project working on PyCharm. What does it mean?

I didn't get any tooltip when hovering over this icon to tell me what it meant, nor did I find any reference to it in a Google search.

[image: This is the error I get]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.py` file is greyed out and marked with an `X` in the Project View because you chose the option "Mark as Plain Text". You can reverse it by choosing "Mark as 'Python'". Both options are available by right-clicking on the file in Project View.

> [Exclude files and folders](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/indexing.html#exclude)
>
> Marking dynamically generated files as excluded can speed up the indexing and overall IDE performance. Excluded files remain a part of a project, but are ignored by code completion, navigation, indexing, and inspections.

[image: screenshot of PyCharm right-click on Project View]